# BizTalk 2016 Feature Pack 2 + ESB Toolkit 2.4 = CreateFaultMessage Exception

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2016

I have an orchestration that throws the exception below when calling `Microsoft.Practices.ESB.ExceptionHandling.ExceptionMgmt.CreateFaultMessage()`.

[image: Type 'System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReceivedFault' in Assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' is not marked as serializable]

The same code works on one server, but not another, so probably a config issue.

I have re-installed the ESB Toolkit and checked the IIS app pools, but to no avail.

Comment: It usually is better to include errors as pasted text, rather than a screenshot.  Makes it searchable for others with the error, and also makes it easier for others to search for that error to find a solution.  Also at the moment the image is very slow to load.

Comment: My first recommendation would be to not use ESBT.  How exactly are you using it?  Do you really need to?

Answer (score 0):

I got to the bottom of this eventually...

A .NET component that makes a web service call received (and bubbled up) an exception that the orchestration couldn't serialize. By handling the exception in the .NET component (and rethrowing it as a serializable one) the problem was solved.

Still not sure how it worked on another server though... I guess some code must have changed after all.